# Does Amazon Cloud Drive provide an RSS feed?

Tags: amazon-cloud-drive

My digital picture frame accepts URLs to RSS feeds. Does [Amazon Cloud Drive](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/primephotos?ref=primedp_cloud) provide an RSS feed? In other words, would I be able to point my frame at some Amazon-provided URL and the frame would be able to download pictures?

Comment: http://status.aws.amazon.com/